# Asking for your help with LFSR, linear automaton

Tags: algorithms, cryptography, pseudo-random-generators, shift-register

I am a software developer new to the site. I am currently learning about LFSR ([linear feedback shift register](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register)). Every day I solve a question which is given to me, but today I am lost. I can not solve this one, so I am asking for your help, for hints, or for any thoughts.

> TASK:
>   Make a linear automaton with the help of LFSR of this recurrent sequence:
>
> $s_{n+4} = s_{n+3}+s_{n+1}+s_{n} $
>
> $ f(x)=x^{4}+x^{3}+x+1$

The plus sign stands for XOR I think $\oplus$

I think that's how it starts and I basically need to design a linear automaton with zeros and ones.
Its period is 15? I am thinking of $0^{3}110010101^{4}|0^{3}1\ldots$

How do I construct a *linear automaton* from here?

Comment: Welcome to CS@SE. A definition of the values shifted would be helpful, and of operation/operator $+$.

Comment: hello it basically refers to  $f(x) = x^{4} +x^{3}+x+1 $  i need to make  a linear automat with the help of bits( zeros and ones)

Comment: `bits(zeros and ones)` that should make it easy to specify operation/operator $+$ ($\oplus$?): please do so in the question body (edit your question).

Comment: i tried to edit is as much as i could can you help me with that please ?

Comment: I tried to lend a hand with markdown. I'm afraid there still is some ground to cover before this question is answerable, starting with terminology. I can look up [Linear *Bounded* Automaton](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_bounded_automaton) - I have no idea how to put the tape to good use, and putting "everything" in *state* and *transition function* was considered bad style. Assuming *no bounds*, I can envision a TM with the tape wasted on (endless) output. I seem to remember *cellular automata*, including a linear variety - LSFRs don't *quite* fit.

Comment: Can you give a reference to the origin of the notation/terminology used, to an original task statement?

Comment: unfortunately i can not because it is written in other language,  but i should be using this formula: $s(x)=\frac{((1+x^{r})h(x))}{f(x)}$   if it helps.